# What is the difference between Scope_Identity(), Identity(), @@Identity, and Ident_Current()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

I know `Scope_Identity()`, `Identity()`, `@@Identity`, and `Ident_Current()` all get the value of the identity column, but I would love to know the difference.

Part of the controversy I'm having is what do they mean by scope as applied to these functions above?

I would also love a simple example of different scenarios of using them?

Comment: Don't forget about the parallel execution bug that exists in SQL Server for SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-US;2019779

Comment: @DaviddCeFreitas -- I'm curious to read about the bug, but the link appears to be broken (or at least, it's throwing an ASP error).

Comment: Actually, I found it: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2019779

Comment: Fix had been released as mentioned at that old KB article

Answer (score 547, accepted):

- The `@@identity` function returns the last identity created in the same session.
- The `scope_identity()` function returns the last identity created in the same session and the same scope.
- The `ident_current(name)` returns the last identity created for a specific table or view in any session.
- The `identity()` function is not used to get an identity, it's used to create an identity in a `select...into` query.

The session is the database connection. The scope is the current query or the current stored procedure.

A situation where the `scope_identity()` and the `@@identity` functions differ, is if you have a trigger on the table. If you have a query that inserts a record, causing the trigger to insert another record somewhere, the `scope_identity()` function will return the identity created by the query, while the `@@identity` function will return the identity created by the trigger.

So, normally you would use the `scope_identity()` function.

Comment: I chose this as the answer, because of the "A situation where the scope_identity() and the @@identity..." paragraph. It clarified things more.

Comment: @Guffa - "The session is the database connection". Is session maintained across connections if you are using Connection Pooling?

Comment: This is a role model answer.  In particular, working with SQL and SQL Server can be weird, and this explains things in a very clear, layman's manner, while still being fairly informative.  It doesn't sound like something being communicated between two database specialists, which a LOT of other SE answers do.

Comment: @DaveBlack from what i read: No, session is not maintained in the pool, session is unique for your script-run after connect(). When pooling ... PHP for SQL Server uses ODBC connection pooling. When a connection from the pool is used, the connection state is reset. Closing the connection returns the connection to the pool. (note: see remarks for linux/mac) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-pooling-microsoft-drivers-for-php-for-sql-server

Comment: @SebastianMeine: The probable reason that your answer was deleted is that it doesn't answer the question at all, but rather is a comment. The bug that you are talking about was fixed nine years ago, so it's unlikely that you would find a system where it's not patched. I wouldn't recommend that you shy away from `scope_identity()` just because there was once a bug related to it.

Comment: @Guffa, if the bug was indeed fixed, I agree with you. Do you have evidence, like a KB?

Comment: @SebastianMeine: It's in the kb article that rory.ap linked to: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2019779

Answer (score 59):

Good question.

- `@@IDENTITY`: returns the last identity value generated on your SQL connection (SPID). Most of the time it will be what you want, but sometimes it isn't (like when a trigger is fired in response to an `INSERT`, and the trigger executes another `INSERT` statement).
- `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`: returns the last identity value generated in the current scope (i.e. stored procedure, trigger, function, etc).
- `IDENT_CURRENT()`: returns the last identity value for a specific table. Don't use this to get the identity value from an `INSERT`, it's subject to race conditions (i.e. multiple connections inserting rows on the same table).
- `IDENTITY()`: used when declaring a column in a table as an identity column.

For more reference, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx.

To summarize: if you are inserting rows, and you want to know the value of the identity column for the row **you** just inserted, always use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

Answer (score 28):

If you understand the difference between scope and session then it will be very easy to understand these methods.

A very nice [blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20110212044239/http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/AdamAnderson/08-04-23/T-SQL_The_difference_between_identity_scope_identity_and_ident_current.aspx) by Adam Anderson describes this difference:

> **Session** means the current connection that's executing the command.
>
> **Scope** means the immediate context of a command. Every stored procedure call executes in its own scope, and nested calls execute in a nested scope within the calling procedure's scope. Likewise, a SQL command executed from an application or SSMS executes in its own scope, and if that command fires any triggers, each trigger executes within its own nested scope.

Thus the differences between the three identity retrieval methods are as follows:

> `@@identity` returns the last identity value generated in *this* session but *any* scope.
>
> `scope_identity()` returns the last identity value generated in *this* session and *this* scope.
>
> `ident_current()` returns the last identity value generated for a particular table in *any* session and *any* scope.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer because it actually defines, in the context of SQL, what a scope and session actually are.

Answer (score 15):

Scope means the code context that performs the `INSERT` statement `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, as opposed to the global scope of `@@IDENTITY`.

```
CREATE TABLE Foo(
  ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  Dummy VARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE FooLog(
  ID INT IDENTITY(2,2),
  LogText VARCHAR(100)
)
go
CREATE TRIGGER InsertFoo ON Foo AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO FooLog (LogText) VALUES ('inserted Foo')
  INSERT INTO FooLog (LogText) SELECT Dummy FROM inserted
END

INSERT INTO Foo (Dummy) VALUES ('x')
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @@IDENTITY
```

Gives different results.

Answer (score 7):

`Scope Identity`: Identity of last record added within the stored procedure being executed.

`@@Identity`: Identity of last record added within the query batch, or as a result of the query e.g. a procedure that performs an insert, the then fires a trigger that then inserts a record will return the identity of the inserted record from the trigger.

`IdentCurrent`: The last identity allocated for the table.

Answer (score 6):

To clarify the problem with `@@Identity`:

For instance, if you insert a table and that table has triggers doing inserts, `@@Identity` will return the id from the insert in the trigger (a `log_id` or something), while `scope_identity()` will return the id from the insert in the original table.

So if you don't have any triggers, `scope_identity()` and `@@identity` will return the same value. If you have triggers, you need to think about what value you'd like.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another good explanation from [the book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735666059):

> As for the difference between SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY, suppose that you have a stored procedure P1 with three statements:
>   - An INSERT that generates a new identity value
>   - A call to a stored procedure P2 that also has an INSERT statement that generates a new identity value
>   - A statement that queries the functions SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY
>   The SCOPE_IDENTITY function will return the value generated by P1 (same session and scope). The @@IDENTITY function will return the value generated by P2 (same session irrespective of scope).