# using @@identity when a trigger is fired in response to an INSERT, and the trigger executes another INSERT statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, identity

I have following tables:

```
tbl_workshop
id  int  identity
Name nvarchar(10)
Address nvarchar(40)


tbl_workshop_temp
id int identity
code int
InsUpkey  smallint
```

And I have follwing statements

```
insert into tbl_workshop
    (Name,Address)
     values('x','y')
select @@identity  -- My problem is here
```

And I have following trigger  for insert  too:

```
create trigger InsertedWorkshop
on tbl_workshop
for insert
as
  insert into tbl_workshop_temp
     (code,InsUpKey)
    select id,1
        from inserted
```

when the `select @@identity` statement runs I get the `id` of inserted row in `tbl_workshop_temp` instead of `id` inserted in `tbl_workshop`

I know I must use `scope_identity` but I can't change the code. I just can change my trigger.
What should I do now? Please help me.

Comment: I can think of a kludge that might work but You should really change your code. Why is it impossible to change it to call the correct function?

Comment: Because the code is written with VB6 by the others. And I can change just the database.

Comment: What this SQL Statement is in compiled code that you don't have access to? Really you would need to get this changed but assuming that you are looking for a short term fix I'll post my (horrible) idea.

Comment: @Raymond next time don't let "the others" put bad, ad hoc SQL into their applications - encourage / insist on stored procedures!

Comment: Yes you are right. I'll do it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a case where you must insist the code be fixed by the others. It is broken and will cause data integrity issues where child data is attched to the wrong record. In fact insist that all of the code that uses @@identity in the application be replaced as soon as possible as it is unlikely that incompetent database developers used it in only one place. This is a major bug in their code and they must take responsibility for fixing it. This is a data integrity issue and thus a show-stopper, crtical fix. There can be no excuse for not fixing this code.

Comment: @HLGEM while I agree with you 100% about the optimal course of action, I disagree that this was necessarily due to incompetence. There was a time when `@@IDENTITY` was the prescribed method, and since this app is still running on SQL 2000 I'll hazard a guess that the app was written when that was the "current" version of SQL Server. The code also may be compiled into an application that has no reliable source code, so modifying the app may be more complicated than you would expect. Again, I totally agree that the app should be fixed, just wanted to air those points. :-)

Comment: Scope_identity was the correct thing to use in SQL Server 2000 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't trick `@@identity` to return some different value. What you could do is remove the `IDENTITY` property from the `tbl_workshop_temp` and either not have an incrementing value in that column (just use the same id as `tbl_workshop`), remove the column altogether, or populate it in the trigger this way (this means that it will only work for one row, however):

```
DECLARE @id INT;

SELECT @id = MAX(id) + 1
   FROM dbo.tbl_workshop_temp WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK); -- important

insert into dbo.tbl_workshop_temp
     (id,code,InsUpKey)
    select @id,id,1
        from inserted;
```

With SQL Server 2005 and above you could get more clever - you could change the above such that it used `ROW_NUMBER()` to handle multiple rows, or you could use an `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` instead (no pun intended) and simply change the order of the insert statements. But with SQL Server 2000 your options really are limited...

Comment: +1 This will fail if there is any additional code not shown that does multi row inserts however as `id` is presumably intended to be unique in `tbl_workshop_temp`

Comment: @Martin, yes, that's an important disclaimer... I'm going to add it to the answer... thanks.

Comment: @Aaron Bertan I changed your code and used this trigger. Am I doing right?
`create trigger InsertedWorkshop
on tbl_workshop
for insert
as

declare @id int
select @id=id from inserted
insert into tbl_workshop_temp (id,code,insupkey)
      select @id,id,1
         from inserted`
I just want a unique key in my `id` field so I used the `id` of `tbl_workshop`. won't I have any problem when two users insert two records simultaneously?

Comment: In case if table is empty `COALESCE(MAX(id),0) + 1` is better; else you get NULL for id.

Comment: @JustAMartin yep, was keeping the answer here simple because we can assume in most cases tables like this don't suddenly go from having rows to being completely empty.

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920558/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-identity-identity-identity-and-iden) for how each of the identity selections work. You're going to have to change the the code for the initial `INSERT` in order to fix this one. `@@identity` always gets the last id from the session, and since the trigger is part of the same session, you'll have to change the way the ID is picked up in the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can select in the inserted row with where clause like this

```
SELECT ID_FIRST_TABLE FROM TRIGGERED_TABLE WHERE TRIGGERED_ID = @@Identity
```