# Trying to replicate Identity in a different column for x number of rows. SQL server Stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I want to add my identity to another column, in x number of rows.  I can get this to repeat for two rows using this code in my stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertReport3] @incdate INT,
                                      @inctime VARCHAR(7),
                                      @inv1    VARCHAR(30),
                                      @inv2    VARCHAR(30),
                                      @inv3    VARCHAR(30),
                                      @inctype VARCHAR(20),
                                      @incnar  TEXT,
                                      @incloc  TEXT,
                                      @no      INT
AS
    INSERT INTO IncidentReport
                (I_Date_Incident,
                 I_Time,
                 IncidentType,
                 I_Narrative,
                 I_Location,
                 I_ID,
                 U_no_fk)
    VALUES     (@incdate,
                @inctime,
                @inctype,
                @incnar,
                @incloc,
                @inv1,
                @no);

    UPDATE Incidentreport
    SET    I_reportno = @@IDENTITY
    WHERE  I_no = @@IDENTITY;

    INSERT INTO IncidentReport
                (I_reportno,
                 I_Date_Incident,
                 I_Time,
                 IncidentType,
                 I_Narrative,
                 I_Location,
                 I_ID,
                 U_no_fk)
    VALUES     (@@IDENTITY,
                @incdate,
                @inctime,
                @inctype,
                @incnar,
                @incloc,
                @inv2,
                @no);
```

Once I get up to three with that code It increments by one, only pulling the previous identity, thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using MS SQL Server you should be using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@identity`. Justification can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920558/). I think this will fix the problem you are experiencing.