# get id from select in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

My question might sound really stupid, but I am stuck. Here is the pseudo code of what I am trying to do in SQL Server

```
if exists(select id from employee where Email='saghir@abc.com')
begin
    insert in tasks with selected id
end
else
begin
    insert in employee value Email='blah';
    insert in tasks with new id in employee
end
```

Hopes for you suggestions.. .

Comment: _"This Code is useless"_ Yes, because it has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use variable

```
declare @foundId int

select @foundId = id from employee where Email='saghir@abc.com'

if @foundId is not null
begin
    insert in tasks (... @foundId... )
end
else
begin
    insert in employee value Email='blah';
    insert in tasks with new id in employee
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Scope_Identity()` to get the last inserted key value.

```
if exists(select id from employee where Email='saghir@abc.com')
begin
    insert tasks(employeeid, task) 
    select id, 'new task' from employee where email = 'saghir@abc.com'
end
else
begin
    insert employee (email) values ('blah');
    select @id = Scope_identity();
    insert tasks(employeeid, task) values (@id, 'new task')
end
```

NB. Using `Ident_Current` or `@@Identity` is more prone to undesirable side effects.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Comment: Scope_Identity returns last inserted index, not selected

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @ID int
select @ID=id from employee where Email='saghir@abc.com'
if @ID is  null
begin
    insert into employee (Email,...) values ('saghir@abc.com',...)
    Select @ID=ident_Current('employee')
end

insert into tasks (employee_ID,...) Values (@ID,..)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your pseudo code to shape a stored procedure: `getEmployeeId_byEmail`.

The second block of the stored procedure will obtain the new EmployeeId with `@@Identity`:

```
/* untested */
insert into employee values(/*what ever*/)
insert into task(/*what ever*/, @@Identity)
```

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920558/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-identity-identity-identity-and-ide).

Comment: avoid using the 'sp_' prefix for user-created stored procedures, it's a reserved prefix see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115(v=vs.100).aspx