# Insert variables into separate tables with a relational identifier

Tags: php, sql-server

I need help with some methodology here.

I have 3 `text` inputs in a form `'add_task'`:

```
<form action="page.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="task_string" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="hours" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="minutes" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add Task" />
</form>
```

The form 'creates' a task with a timeline using the inputs above.

Now, I have two tables, `tasks` and `timelines`

I can `INSERT INTO` the tasks table with the `task_string` value, the entry then holds a unique `id` that auto increments.

```
// tasks
+----+------------------+
| id | string           |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | task string here |
+----+------------------+
```

I now need to enter the `minutes` and `hours` values into the `timelines` table but I need to reference the above `tasks.id`

```
//timelines
+----+-------+---------+-----------------------------+
| id | hours | minutes | task_id                     |
+----+-------+---------+-----------------------------+
| 1  | 3     | 29      | // task_id from table above |
+----+-------+---------+-----------------------------+
```

How can I accomplish this using SQL Server and PHP in a multi-user environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`@@IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187342.aspx) for this purpose; An example below. But for a multi user environment you must be using `transaction block` to make sure both the insertion happens successfully.

```
create procedure doDML(@task_string varchar(100),@hours int, @minutes int)
as
begin
declare @lastID int;
insert into tasks values(@task_string);
set @lastID = @@IDENTITY;

insert into timelines values(@hours, @minutes, @lastID);
end
```

Comment: You should use SCOPE_IDENTITY instead of @@IDENTITY. [Stack Overflow
Questions
Tags
Users
Badges
Unanswered
Ask Question
What is the difference between Scope_Identity(), Identity(), @@Identity, and Ident_Current?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1920640/924077)

Comment: @BogdanSahlean, Thanks for pointing that link but in this situation, there is no harm in using @@IDENTITY since you are using it in the same procedure. You can try it and it's guaranteed to work.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean, I read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) that `scope_identity()` is broken and that one should use `output clause` instead.

Comment: @proPhet: SCOPE_IDENTITY may produce wrong results when [parallel plans](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/24/sql-server-2008-scope_identity-bug-with-multi-processor-parallel-plan-and-solution/) are used. But this is not the case with `INSERT ... VALUES (...).` The bug affects SCOPE_IDENTITY() and, also, @@IDENTITY (according to Microsoft Support link).