# How to write thread safe SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have some stored procedures in which multiple queries are being executed. To get last identity of insert I am using `IDENT_CURRENT` which is causuing problem.

My question is can I have lock statements like C# in T-SQL so that it can be thread safe?

EDIT: Code I am using

```
INSERT INTO activities
    (creator
    ,title
    ,description)
VALUES
    (@Creator
    ,@Tile
    ,@Description)

SET @ActivityId = IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.activities');

INSERT INTO [dbo].activity_cfs
    ([activity_id],
    [cf_id],
    [cf_field_name],
    [field_key],
    [value])
SELECT 
    @ActivityId,
    cf_id,
    cf_field_name,
    field_key,
    value
FROM @ActivityCustomFields
```

`@ActivityCustomFields` is my temp table.

Comment: Some code please. We can not assume that you have written correct code :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is quite likely that you should use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms190315.aspx) instead of `IDENT_CURRENT`. There are many explanations how they differ, for example: [What is the difference between Scope_Identity(), Identity(), @@Identity, and Ident_Current?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920558/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-identity-identity-identity-and-ide)

But, if you really need to guarantee that certain part of the code is not being run by several threads at the same time, you can use [`sp_getapplock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx).

---

Based on the code that you added to the question I'm now pretty sure that you should simply use `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, like this:

```
INSERT INTO activities
    (creator
    ,title
    ,description)
VALUES
    (@Creator
    ,@Tile
    ,@Description);

SET @ActivityId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO [dbo].activity_cfs
    ([activity_id],
    [cf_id],
    [cf_field_name],
    [field_key],
    [value])
SELECT 
    @ActivityId,
    cf_id,
    cf_field_name,
    field_key,
    value
FROM @ActivityCustomFields;
```

The `SCOPE_IDENTITY` function returns the last identity created in the same session and the same scope.
The `IDENT_CURRENT` returns the last identity created for a specific table or view in any session. So, if you have several threads that run this procedure simultaneously `IDENT_CURRENT` will see identities generated in other threads, which you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

SCOPE_IDENTITY would be the way to go in my understanding. Please follow following link that in SQL Server when using SCOPE_IDENTITY will always be threadsafe:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?727047-RESOLVED-Is-MSSQL-s-SCOPE_IDENTITY()-thread-safe