# How to protect assignment of the same value by SCOPE_IDENTITY()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with a situation when many users insert a record to the database in the same time and in column scope_id there are duplicated values.
Is there a way to protect duplication of value?

```
@scope_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

I thought about a trigger but maybe is a simpler solution.(Checking before that id is in the database doesn't always work.)

Comment: Declare the column as `identity`, let sql-server set  the values.

Comment: @Serg I don't want use identity because this column is linked with another table.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920558/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-identity-identity-identity-and-ide

Comment: Can you share the table's DDL statement and the insert statement that's returning the wrong scope_id()?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is already isolated to each connection so you wouldn't be picking up values relating to other users.

Comment: The question title is misleading: the column is NOT an identity column, and the OP does not want to use an identity column.

Comment: What about creating a Unique index and retrying? If you don't have much load could work, although Identity or Sequence is the way to go. Identity shouldn't be a problem with Foreign Keys

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 12+ I would suggest to take advantage of the `SEQUENCE` object ([MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx)).

Sample code from the above reference:

Creating the sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Test.CountBy1  
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;  
GO
```

Using it:

```
DECLARE @NextID int ;  
SET @NextID = NEXT VALUE FOR Test.CountBy1;  
-- Some work happens  
INSERT Test.Orders (OrderID, Name, Qty)  
    VALUES (@NextID, 'Rim', 2) ;  
GO
```

The `NEXT VALUE` statement consumes the next value of the sequence before even trying to insert a record.

Comment: I should say this `-- Some work happens` looks scary . They'd better say `-- Some cautiously programmed work happens`.

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for can be achieved by using the T-SQL functions `NEWSEQUENTIALID`.  This generates sequential global unique identifiers to be stored in an attribute of a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER type. The GUIDs are guaranteed to be unique across space and time

It can be used at the time of declaring the table as well For example:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (ColumnA uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID())
```