# C# - Call stored procedure with type

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to call a stored procedure from my database, but it also needs a List of attributes as a type and I placed a cursor on that type. But everytime I execute the command I get an exception back that the cursor is not open.

**What I have now already**

```
        using (Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            Connection.Open();

            using (Command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                Command.Connection = Connection;
                Command.CommandText = "CreateCharacter";
                Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Skills", skills);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountId", accountId);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassId", masteryId);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RaceId", raceId);
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);

                try
                {
                    return character = LoadCharacter(Convert.ToInt32(Command.ExecuteScalar()));
                }

                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Type**

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.AttributeList AS TABLE
(
    AttributeId integer,
    [Level] integer
);
GO
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CreateCharacter (@Attributes AS dbo.AttributeList 
READONLY, @AccountId integer, @ClassId integer, @RaceId integer, @Name 
varchar(12))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE AttributeCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    AttributeId,
    [Level]
FROM @Attributes

INSERT INTO Character
    VALUES (@ClassId, @RaceId, NULL, @Name, 1, 0, 0)
DECLARE @Id integer
DECLARE @AttributeId integer
DECLARE @AttributeLevel integer
SET @Id = IDENT_CURRENT('Character');

UPDATE Account
SET CharacterId = @Id
WHERE Id = @AccountId

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Attribute_Character
        VALUES (@AttributeId, @Id, @AttributeLevel)
    FETCH NEXT FROM AttributeCursor INTO @AttributeId, @AttributeLevel
END
RETURN @Id;
END
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but ident_current is probably not what you want, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920558/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-identity-identity-identity-and-ide

Comment: Amazingly, your error is because you don't open the cursor (or close or deallocate it). But you can and should eliminate the cursor anyway. Look into using OUTPUT and inserted.id so you can use set based operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to send a Table param you just have to build a DataTable on the C# side:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("AttributeID", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Level", typeof(int));

//Add data
table.Rows.Add(new []{1, 2});

//More code
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Attributes", table);
```

And I think you don't need a cursor in the Procedure. Just insert the data:

```
INSERT INTO Attribute_Character(AttributeId, AttributeLevel)
SELECT AttributeId, AttributeLevel
FROM @Attributes
```

Comment: I dind't downvote your answer, I upvoted it and accepted it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Still wrong. I downvoted. You do not NEED a DataTable - there is a better more direct way, which is what DataTable actually uses.

Comment: Cool @tomtom waiting for your answer then

Comment: @TomTom, downvotes are for unhelpful answers, not answers that aren't the single best way. And if you are talking about using IEnumerable of SqlDatarecord then IMO that is not more direct.