# How to call first SQL Server stored procedure to second stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have three tables:

- TB1 : P (p_id (pk),p_name,p_description)
- TB2: PV (pv_id (pk),p_id(fk),v_id(fk),cost)
- TB3: V (V_id (pk),name)

I have used below SQL Server stored procedure "Addp" which inserts `p_name` and `p_description` on being called.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddP 
    (@name CHAR(50), 
     @description VARCHAR(255)) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PCount INT

    SELECT @PCount = Count(P_ID) 
    FROM P
    WHERE P_Name= @name

    IF @PCount = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO P(P_Name, P_Description)
        VALUES(@name, @description)
    END

    RETURN @@IDENTITY
END
```

Now, I would like to create another procedure where I can insert "v_id" and cost along with "Addp" stored procedure.My second SP looks like following. My question is How should I call my first stored procedure into second new stored procedure. So that when I execute my second stored procedure I should be able to insert p_name,p_description,vi,cost everything in one shot?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddPWithV (@vi int, @cost decimal(12,4))
AS
BEGIN

        INSERT INTO PV (V_ID, Cost)
        VALUES(@vi, @cost)
    Return @@IDENTITY
END;
```

I am new to stored procedure.So,please guide me through explanation.
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what does more filed mean?

Comment: @Mr.AF.. It was typo. It has to to be fields..so that I can call the procedure and can insert values for those fields

Comment: You can't add data for v_id and cost columns if the columns don't exist in P to host them.

Comment: Don't use `@@IDENTITY`, instead use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920558/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-identity-identity-identity-and-ide

Answer (score 0):

Just declare twor more variables 
Shown as below:

```
DECLARE @_vid INT
DECLARE @_cost numeric(18,2) // as per your column daya type 

Select @_vid =vid from TB3 where name =@name ;

Select  @_cost = cost from TB2 where 
P_id in (select p_id from TB1 where name =@name );
```

Now you have both values you can insert where ever you want ..

Comment: ..My issue is I just want to INSERT  v_id  from TB3

Comment: You Are passing  Name in storeprocedure ,
From that  name you can get vid from TB3 as  shown is in  my answer.