# How to select last inserted value of the table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select the ID of the last inserted value on my database in SQL Server. I tried many ways for example `@@IDENTITY`, `IDENT_CURRENT('TableName')`,  `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` but nothing was possible. Also I had tried to order by but nothing worked for me.

In my code I have

```
Select top(1)* 
from Ferramenta_Limpeza 
where Ferramenta_ID!='' and (Id_Gestao between'1' and '434')
order by Id_Gestao desc
```

My logic was  to find the value that is diferent of empty, between 1 and 434. The problem is that this, show always the last value even if I insert another record on 'ID =1', this means that I tryed to update the value of Id 1 and when I tryed the same select to show the las value iserted or updated, the code just show me the last row

Can Someone explain how to do it?

Comment: Are you inserting the data? What is the datatype of `Id_Gestao`? If it's an `INT` don't compare it to character values.

Comment: my Id_Gestao is int. I didn't understand What you mean. I@WEI_DBA I 'm not comparing the value of Id_Gestao.

Comment: What do you mean by - even if I insert another record on 'ID =1' ? do you mean Id_Gestao = 1?

Comment: Does your table have an IDENTITY column?   Which column is it?

Answer (score 0):

When using the @@IDENTITY, IDENT_CURRENT('TableName'),  SCOPE_IDENTITY() you must have a column having a IDENTITY increment value.

Ex : Create the temp table

```
 CREATE TABLE #TableName
 (
   ID [int] IDENTITY(1,1),
   Name_value VARCHAR(100)
 )
```

-- execute the insert and this will give you the last inserted value

```
 insert into #TableName (Name_value) values ('test1')
 insert into #TableName (Name_value) values ('test2')
 insert into #TableName (Name_value) values ('test3')

 select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Make sure that you read the following link and understand the difference of the output

[What is the difference between Scope_Identity(), Identity(), @@Identity, and Ident_Current()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920558/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-identity-identity-identity-and-ide)

Comment: *you should have an identity column* - no, not you **should** - you ***MUST HAVE*** an identity column.