# How do I get a stored procedure to insert @@identity of previous inserts AUTO ID

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

[image]

Image above is order details table and the orderID is foreign key ref orders table.

[image]

This is my orders table which will generate a id when a table is inserted via this stored procedure below. PK OrderID

[image]

The stored procedure that inserts a table will happen first which will generate a orderID. I will then run this stored procedure below wanting to insert the last inserted orderID from orders into Orderdetails table using @@identity

[image]

but when I try to insert it comes up with this error saying the orderID is null

[image]

Have I written a wrong SQL statement to perform my desired action of inserting previously generated ID from one table to another

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Cdob. Consider providing more information without external links for images and some code so people can know how to help you. For more information, take a look at [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I haven't read/looked at your images, as they are unlikely to help. If you do want to supply code or data, do so as `text`, so that we can consume the information. I suggest, however, looking at the `OUTPUT` clause.

Comment: You might also want to avoid using @@identity. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920558/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-identity-identity-identity-and-ide

Comment: I've voted to close this topic as the OP is expecting us to transcribe their code to help them. We are therefore unable to replicate their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a few things.
First of all, you can't *invoke* @@IDENTITY. It's purpose is to save the identity value of a row you just inserted. Also, it's got issues with scoping, so you should use SCOPE_IDENTITY instead.

Your first procedure needs to return the inserted identity to the outer wrapper. This can be accomplished by using an OUTPUT parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.testinsert333
(
    @TableID TINYINT
    ,@OrderID   INT OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Orders (Orders.TableID)
    VALUES (@TableID)
    SET @OrderID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

Your second procedure needs to just accept @OrderID. There's no way for this thread to snag an inserted identity value from a different thread. It must come in as a parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.testinsert666
(
    @OrderID    INT
    ,@ProductID INT
    ,@Price INT
    ,@Quantity SMALLINT
    ,@OrderStatus BIT
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetails
                (
                    OrderID
                    ,ProductID
                    ,Price
                    ,Quantity
                    ,OrderStatus
                )
    SELECT  @OrderID
            ,@ProductID
            ,@Price
            ,@Quantity
            ,@OrderStatus
END
GO
```

Now to tie all this together, they need to be called together, as in the example below.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @OrderID INT
    EXEC dbo.testinsert333 @TableID = 1, @OrderID = @OrderID OUTPUT

    EXEC dbo.testinsert666
            @OrderID = @OrderID
            ,@ProductID = @ProductID
            ,@Price = @Price
            ,@Quantity = @Quantity
            ,@OrderStatus = @OrderStatus
END
```

However, the best approach is to nest these two procedures into one, like below.

```
CREATE dbo.usp_AllInWonder
(
    @TableID INT
    ,@ProductID INT
    ,@Price INT
    ,@Quantity SMALLINT
    ,@OrderStatus BIT
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @OrderID INT

    INSERT INTO dbo.Orders (Orders.TableID)
    VALUES (@TableID)

    SET @OrderID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetails
        (
            OrderID
            ,ProductID
            ,Price
            ,Quantity
            ,OrderStatus
        )
    SELECT  @OrderID
            ,@ProductID
            ,@Price
            ,@Quantity
            ,@OrderStatus
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove line 13 from `testinsert666`.  You're passing in the OrderID, so you don't need to assign it there.  Any call to `@@identity` ( or preferably `scope_identity()`) would be in `testinsert333'.

Answer (score 0):

For you to use the @@IDENTITY in testinsert666, you need you have the insert creating @@IDENTITY to happen in the procedure testinsert666. testinsert666 can only be used in the same session it was generated.
See [@@IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)