# How to check which primary key a record was assigned to in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

I'm using the OleDBConnectivity system to connect and use a Microsoft Access database.

I'm adding a record to the table in the database called "PayInfo", and the primary key is automatically set to the next available integer. How do I check what the value of the primary key it was assigned to is? I know this is probably an awful idea, but the only thing I could think of was to re-read the database using the entered values. The issue with this, though it's very unlikely, is that its possible to have 2 identical records stored in the database, their only difference being the primary key, and I need to be able to read the specific one.

My current subroutine for adding the record to the database is as follows:

```
OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
connection.Open();

// The SQL statement:
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PayInfo ([UserID], [FullName], [CardType], [CardNo], [CVV], [ExpDate], [Address])" +
                      "VALUES ('" + Global.UserID.ToString() + "','" + PayInfo[6] + "','" + PayInfo[0] + "','" + PayInfo[1] + "','" + PayInfo[2] + "','" + exp + "','" + adress + "')";

command.Connection = connection;

command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //executes the SQL command.

connection.Close();
return true;  //Successful transaction
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After executing your insert query, you need to execute another query to get the generated primary key:

```
command.Parameters.Clear();
command.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
int primaryKey = Convert.ToInt32(Command.ExecuteScalar());
```

See [Microsoft: Retrieving Identity or Autonumber Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-identity-or-autonumber-values) for more details:

> The Jet database engine does not support the execution of multiple
> statements in a batch or the use of output parameters, so it is not
> possible to use either of these techniques to return the new
> Autonumber value assigned to an inserted row. However, you can add
> code to the RowUpdated event handler that executes a separate SELECT
> @@IDENTITY statement to retrieve the new Autonumber value.

Comment: `@@IDENTITY` might not be the right choice, e.g. if `PayInfo` has any triggers-- see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920558/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-identity-identity-identity-and-ide)