# Problem in Capturing the Primary Key (shift_id) when Registering a New Shift

Tags: sql, sql-server

Description of the problem:

The problem in the process of registering a new Turno, through the stored procedure "Turno_reg," lies in the lack of capturing the primary key "shift_id" after inserting the shift data into the corresponding table. Even though the shift registration is successful, capturing the value of "turno_id" results in a null value (NULL).

```
--EXEC Turno_reg '20354561124', 'LL', 'Descripción del turno 1', 'A', '08:00:00', '16:00:00', '08:30:00', '15:30:00', 'A', 1, '1,3,5'
 
 
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Turno_reg]
(
    @empresa_codigo varchar(11),
    @turno_nombre varchar(25),
    @turno_descripcion varchar(50),
    @turno_tipo char(1),
    @turno_inicio time(0),
    @turno_fin time (0),
    @turno_refrigerio_inicio time (0),
    @turno_refrigerio_fin time (0),
    @turno_status char(1),
    @horario_id bigint,
    @dias_repetidos VARCHAR(MAX) -- Un parámetro que contiene los días en que se aplica el turno (p. ej., "1,3,5" para lunes, miércoles, viernes)
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Verificar si los sgtes datos son NULL o cadenas vacías y generar el mensaje correspondiente
    IF COALESCE(@turno_nombre, '') = '' OR COALESCE(@turno_tipo, '') = '' OR COALESCE(@turno_inicio, '') = '' OR COALESCE(@turno_fin, '')= '' OR COALESCE(@turno_status, '') = '' OR COALESCE(@horario_id, '') = '' 
    BEGIN
        SELECT Rpta = 1, Msg = 'ERROR! DATOS INCOMPLETOS'
        RETURN
    END
 
    DECLARE @bdEmpresa varchar(20)
 
    SELECT  @bdEmpresa = e.empresa_basededatos
    FROM Empresas e 
    WHERE e.empresa_codigo = LTRIM(RTRIM(@empresa_codigo))
 
    IF ISNULL(@bdEmpresa,'') <> ''  -- SI NO ES VACIO SIGNIFICA QUE SI EXISTE LA EMPRESA
    BEGIN
 
        BEGIN
            -- Crear una tabla temporal para almacenar la clave primaria
            CREATE TABLE #ClavePrimaria (ID INT);
 
            -- Insertar el turno en la tabla "Turno"
            EXEC ('INSERT INTO ' + @bdEmpresa + '.dbo.Turno('+
                'turno_nombre, '+
                'turno_descripcion, '+
                'turno_tipo, '+
                'turno_inicio, '+
                'turno_fin, '+
                'turno_refrigerio_inicio, '+
                'turno_refrigerio_fin, '+
                'turno_status, '+
                'horario_id)'+
                'VALUES('
                +''''+@turno_nombre+ ''','
                +''''+@turno_descripcion+ ''','
                +''''+@turno_tipo+ ''','
                +''''+@turno_inicio+ ''','
                +''''+@turno_fin+ ''','
                +''''+@turno_refrigerio_inicio+ ''','
                +''''+@turno_refrigerio_fin+ ''','
                +''''+@turno_status+ ''','
                +''''+@horario_id+''')');
 
            -- Capturar la clave primaria en la tabla temporal
            INSERT INTO #ClavePrimaria (ID)
            VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY());
 
            -- Realizar una consulta SELECT para ver la clave primaria
            SELECT ID FROM #ClavePrimaria;
 
        END
 
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        SELECT Rpta = 1, Msg = 'LOS DATOS DE LA EMPRESA SON INCORRECTOS'
    END
END
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHJ1J.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jpls.png)

Comment: move the scope_identity insert inside the exec

Comment: also, you should really use SP_EXECUTESQL with real parameters, not hardcoded EXEC commands

Comment:  [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is dynamic SQL is run in a different scope, hence `scope_identity()` won't work.

You'll need to capture scope_identity *inside* your dynamic SQL, then output it through parameters using `sp_executesql`. Using `sp_executesql` has the added bonus that you can parameterize your dynamic SQL and make it safe from injection attack.

Here's how I'd do it. Notice I used `quotename` on your database name to make that safe, and parameterized everything else. Also notice the declared `output` parameter which lets you capture the `scope_identity()` from your dynamic SQL, and then output it through the parameters.

Since you're only inserting a single row of data, this is much easier than dealing with a temp table with a single column that expects only a single row. You can just work with the parameter.

Please also note, there is more than one way to capture the most recent identify from a table, each with their own pros and cons. I prefer `scope_identity()` in *most* cases, but it's worth being aware of the others. Check out this SO article on the matter. [What is the difference between Scope_Identity(), Identity(), @@Identity, and Ident_Current()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920558/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-identity-identity-identity-and-ide)

If any of this is alien to you, please read the docs on [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
CREATE TABLE #ClavePrimaria (ID INT);
declare @shift_id int -- I added this. This is going to be the inserted identity value

-- Insertar el turno en la tabla "Turno"
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = concat
    (
        'INSERT INTO ', quotename(@bdEmpresa), '.dbo.Turno
        (
            turno_nombre,
            turno_descripcion,
            turno_tipo,
            turno_inicio,
            turno_fin,
            turno_refrigerio_inicio,
            turno_refrigerio_fin,
            turno_status,
            horario_id
        )
        VALUES
        (
            @turno_nombre,
            @turno_descripcionm
            @turno_tipo,
            @turno_inicio,
            @turno_fin,
            @turno_refrigerio_inicio,
            @turno_refrigerio_fin,
            @turno_status,
            @horario_id,

        )
    
        select @shift_id = scope_identity() -- Added this. This captures the identity from inside the dsql, and puts it in the OUTPUT parameter
        '
    )

exec sp_executesql
    @SQL,
    N'
        @turno_nombre varchar(25),
        @turno_descripcion varchar(50),
        @turno_tipo char(1),
        @turno_inicio time(0),
        @turno_fin time (0),
        @turno_refrigerio_inicio time (0),
        @turno_refrigerio_fin time (0),
        @turno_status char(1),
        @horario_id bigint,
        @shift_id int output
    ',
        @turno_nombre,
        @turno_descripcion,
        @turno_tipo,
        @turno_inicio,
        @turno_fin,
        @turno_refrigerio_inicio,
        @turno_refrigerio_fin,
        @turno_status,
        @horario_id,
        @shift_id output -- Added this to capture the OUTPUT parameter

    select @ScopeIdentity -- You can now use this however you like
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use an output parameter with sp_executesql, eg for

```
create table foo(id int identity, a int)
```

Either

```
declare @id int
exec sp_executesql N'insert into foo(a) values(@a); set @id = scope_identity()', N'@a int, @id int output', @a = 1, @id = @id output
select @id
```

or add an OUTPUT clause to insert the ID into your temp table, which is  visible in the nested batch

```
create table #id(id int)
exec sp_executesql N'insert into foo(a) output inserted.id into #id values(@a)', N'@a int', @a = 1
select * from #id
```