# How to get the value I entered in SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, dapper

I am using the following query to store values ​​in a table:

```sql
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TB_Templates] ([DescTemplate], [Template], [User])
VALUES ('teste', 'teste', 'teste')
```

The table that stores the values ​​has the following columns:

```
[IDTemplate] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
[DescTemplate] [varchar](255) NOT NULL
[Template] [varchar](max) NOT NULL
[User] [varchar](255) NOT NULL
```

After I store this value, I need to know the ID that was created with the row that I inserted to work with the value in my C# Web API.

Is there any way for me to know which `IDTemplate` was created?

Comment: There is a ")" missing in your Query. I guess that's just a typo?

Comment: Is [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) what you're looking for? (Also discussed in that link is @@IDENTITY.)

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920558/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-identity-identity-identity-and-ide for some options and their differences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your service method return integer for the row you just added.

```cs
return connection.QueryFirst<int>(
    @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[TB_Templates] ([DescTemplate] ,[Template] ,[User])
      VALUES (@descTemplate, @template, @user);

      SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();",
    new { descTemplate,  template, user }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Couple of advice, If you can put the insert into a stored procedure like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spClient_Upsert
    @ClientID INT OUTPUT,
    @ClientName NVARCHAR(100),
    @ClientCode NVARCHAR(12)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Check if the record already exists based on the unique constraint
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Client WHERE ClientCode = @ClientCode)
    BEGIN
        -- Update the existing record
        UPDATE dbo.Client
        SET
            ClientName = @ClientName
        WHERE ClientCode = @ClientCode;

        SET @ClientID = (SELECT ClientID FROM dbo.Client WHERE ClientCode = @ClientCode);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Insert a new record
        INSERT INTO dbo.Client (ClientName, ClientCode)
        VALUES (@ClientName, @ClientCode);

        SET @ClientID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    END
END;


        DynamicParameters p = new();
        p.Add(name: "@ClientID", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
        p.Add(name: "@ClientName", data.ClientName);
        p.Add(name: "@ClientCode", data.ClientCode);
        p.Add(name: "@output", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

    using IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    await connection.ExecuteAsync(storedProcedureName: "[dbo].[spClient_Upsert]", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
     
  int ClientID = p.Get<int>(name: "@ClientID");
```