How to get identity of another table record inside after insert trigger caused by a transaction for current scope and Session?
I have an AFTER INSERT trigger on a table named FileInformation.
The trigger performs two updates on this table.
It works fine when FileInformation is inserted into solely. But when a record is inserted into this table in a transaction with another table from my application layer, one of the updates that is trying to get the Identity value from the other table and update the inserted record of FileInformation table with that value does not work and can not get the identity value from the record being inserted into the other table inside the transaction.
This is what my trigger looks like:
ALTER TRIGGER [Infrastructure].[UpdateFileInformationAfterInsert]  
ON [Infrastructure].[FileInformation]  
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @InsertedCode AS int;
    DECLARE @SQLQuery AS nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @DataBaseTableName AS nvarchar(100);
    DECLARE @DataBaseTableRowID AS uniqueidentifier;
    DECLARE @ProjectComponentID AS uniqueidentifier;
    DECLARE @BoundedContext AS nvarchar(200);
    DECLARE @Code AS int;

    SELECT
        @InsertedCode = Code, 
        @DataBaseTableName = DataBaseTableName, 
        @DataBaseTableRowID = DataBaseTableRowID, 
        @ProjectComponentID = ProjectComponentID 
    FROM
        inserted

    SET @BoundedContext = (SELECT Name 
                           FROM [Infrastructure].[BoundedContext] 
                           WHERE ID = (SELECT BoundedContextID 
                                       FROM [Infrastructure].[ProjectComponent] 
                                       WHERE ID = @ProjectComponentID))
    SET @SQLQuery = CONCAT('select @Code=Code from [', @BoundedContext ,'].[',@DataBaseTableName,'] where ID=''',@DataBaseTableRowID,'''')

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery ,N'@Code int output',@Code=@Code output

    UPDATE [Infrastructure].[FileInformation]
    SET DataBaseTableRowCode = @Code
    WHERE Code = @InsertedCode

    IF (SELECT Value FROM [Infrastructure].[ConfigurationSetting] 
        WHERE Name = N'FileSavingMethod') = N'0'
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @FileSavingRootPath AS nvarchar(MAX)
        SET @FileSavingRootPath = (SELECT Value 
                                   FROM [Infrastructure].[ConfigurationSetting] 
                                   WHERE Name = N'FileSavingRootPath')

        UPDATE [Infrastructure].[FileInformation]
        SET FileSavePath = CONCAT('~\', @FileSavingRootPath, '\', [Infrastructure].[GetSubDirectory] (@InsertedCode))
        WHERE Code = @InsertedCode
    END
END

As I mentioned, the first UPDATE in the code above does not work when a transaction with another table is being executed.
My question: I have read some answers about SCOPE_IDENTITY, @@IDENTITY, IDENT_CURRENT. Is it possible to get the identity value from the other table (by using its name like IDENT_CURRENT('tablename')) which in my code is @DataBaseTableName BUT inside the current scope and session?

this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920558/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-identity-identity-identity-and-ide

You making trigger mistake 101 - and assuming inserted only contains a single row. It may not, you need to handle it as the set it is. The official documentation on this is very good.

I don't quite get what you mean, you have a table X being inserted into by some code, but who's inserting into FileInformation? Why can't that code populate the fields needed after it populated the Table X? And why would the stand-alone version work, while other version don't, what has transaction to do with the whole thing

And you don't have an insert in your trigger, so how is scope_identity relevant to your question?

@DaleK Can scope_identity get identity value from another table by using the tablename?

@DaleK as far as I am aware IDENT_CURRENT is for getting the value using tablename, but , since you mentioned I was wondered.

Do fix your trigger BTW... if you leave it as it is, you are going to get a nasty surprise, which will be hard to debug, the first time someone does an insert with 0 or > 1 rows.

@DaleK Thank you again, but due to the impossibility of using Ident_Current('tablename') for current scope, I am thinking of moving the after insert updates into my application layer code since the trigger is going to be useless according to my purpose.

Even better... triggers should be avoided where possible.

IDENT_CURRENT should not be considered. It is not safe to use for concurrent activity.
Is NOT possible to get the identity value from the other table by using its name like IDENT_CURRENT('tablename'). With SQL Server 2016 you can consider using sp_set_session_context to set a variable that is within your session scope only.
Set using:
DECLARE @SI NUMERIC(38,0)= SCOPE_IDENTITY();
EXEC [sys].[sp_set_session_context] @key = 'BlaBlaKeyName'
                                   ,@value = @SI
                                   ,@read_only = 1;  

Retrieve using:
SELECT @SavedIdent = CONVERT(NUMERIC(38,0),SESSION_CONTEXT(N'BlaBlaKeyName'));


Thank you Bart, I just needed an SQL expert opinion on my question. If there will be no Possible answers I will mark yours as the accepted answer.

And where and when should I call EXEC [sys].[sp_set_session_context] @key = 'BlaBlaKeyName' ,@value = SCOPE_IDENTITY() ,@read_only = 1;? Considering the record is being inserted from my application layer and could be inserted into any table!

It is the first step of the After_Insert trigger. Before any other action gets a chance to overwrite the value inside SCOPE_IDENTITY().

Just a little nitpick, but you can't call functions in SP parameters. Not sure about the idea in general either :)

@siggemannen Good catch. You will need to save SCOPE_IDENTITY() in a variable before using that inside the sp_set_session_context call.
